# C# Winforms Globally catch thread exception and stay in thread context

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, exception

I would like to catch all exceptions in a global handler.
But my requirement is to stay in the context of the thread which threw the exception!
Unfortunalety all global handlers like `Application.ThreadException` or  `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` are running in the main thread. 
But i want to catch the exception in the thread throwing the exception.
The reason is that I want to read global variables which are declared with the attribute `ThreadStatic`.

Is this possible in C# Winforms?

Comment: Why not simply starting thread work inside `try/catch`? I mean `try/catch` should be the first  code to run for any thread you want to access its `[ThreadStatic]` fields.

Comment: You are better off trying to handle exceptions on the threads that generate them, global error handlers should be a last resort

Comment: yeah, thats correct. But Im dealing with a few millions of legacy code which was converted from a coding language which has no exception handling at all.
fyi if one line of code had a failure the runtime just continued with the next line of code. Now the code is converted to C# and therefore I need a global thread context based exception handling, because I do not have the option to make a try catch aropund each thread started